# Multi-Process (CPU-only) JAX

Tags: jax

How does CPU-only multi-process parallelism work with JAX?

Base upon [Using JAX in multi-host and multi-process environments](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multi_process.html), I attempted the example (`pmap` over `psum`) by running slurm with

`$> srun -n4 -c1 python multiproc.py`

with `jax.distributed.initialize()`, but the processes are each only recognising `jax.devices() = [CpuDevice(id=0)]`

Answer (score 0):

I missed the discussion [How to use JAX pmap with multiple processes? #9688](https://github.com/google/jax/discussions/9688) when the question was posted.

It seems `jax.distributed.initialize()` will not replicate `MPI.COMM_WORLD` functionality across CPU processes for the foreseeable future.

At this stage it seems the options involve extensions such as [mpi4jax](https://github.com/mpi4jax/mpi4jax) and [alpa](https://github.com/alpa-projects/alpa).